# Docker durante o desenvolvimento

Tags: docker

Comecei a estudar o uso de Docker e surgiu uma dúvida que ainda não consegui entender:

Imaginem que eu tenho um script python que eu quero rodar dentro do meu container, então eu vou lá e crio o seguinte `DockerFile`

```
FROM python:3
ADD hello_world.py /
CMD [ "python", "./hello_world.py" ]
```

Até aqui tudo 100%, criei a imagem, subi o container e consegui realizar os testes que eu precisava no meu ambiente de desenvolvimento.

Imagine que agora eu quero fazer apenas uma pequena alteração no meu código `hello_world.py` para realizar outro teste.

Eu preciso realizar todo o procedimento novamente? Criar a imagem, subir ela e etc?

Na minha mente isso parece improdutivo, afinal seria muito mais fácil eu simplesmente executar o script na minha máquina. E usar o container apenas para fazer os testes finais criando um ambiente de homologação.

O Docker realmente funciona desta forma? Ele não foi feito para o programador testar enquanto desenvolve? Ou eu estou usando ele incorretamente?

Comment: Uso docker em desenvolvimento e produção, e usamos a opção `-v` para fazer o link entre a pasta da maquina e o conteiner durante o desenvolvimento, trabalho em php, então o apache cuida de identificar as alterações dos arquivos e não é necessário subir o container novamente, no seu exemplo como o comando executado é um script creio que tenha que derrubar e subir o container novamente para Atualizar o script, porem com o `-v` economiza tempo na criação da imagem nova

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim você pode utilizar o contêiner para desenvolvimento, para que você possa entender melhor vou fazer alguns esclarecimentos.

1. O comando `CMD` será executado apenas uma vez, quando seu contêiner for *startado*.
2. Para efetuar uma alteração no seu arquivo `hello_world.py` e para que
   a mesma se reflita no contêiner, será necessário você linkar o
   volume onde encontra seu arquivo com o volume do contêiner.

Para que você possa utilizar o contêiner como ambiente de desenvolvimento te sugiro o seguinte:

1. Alterar o comando `ADD hello_world.py /` para `ADD hello_world.py /scripts` guardando assim todos seus scripts em uma pasta.
2. Remover o `CMD` do seu `Dockerfile`, assim para rodar seu script você conectaria no bash do seu contêiner e rodaria o script.
3. Segunda alteração é na hora de executar o comando `docker run`, nele você adiconaria o `-v .:/scripts`, assim linkando a pasta onde está seu Dockerfile e scripts, com a pasta scripts criada dentro do contêiner. Sendo assim todas as alterações que fizer na sua maquina vão ser refletidas nos arquivos no container
4. Para executar os scripts você pode acessar seu contêiner (o mesmo que já possui) com `docker exec -it #hashDoContainer bash` (para descobrir a hash do contêiner, basta utilizar o comando `docker ps` e identificar o seu). Assim você acessará seu contêiner e poderá rodar qualquer script que quiser

Answer (score 2):

Adicione a chave `-v` no comando que inicia o container do Docker (`docker run`). Essa opção não pode ser incluida no Dockerfile para manter a portabilidade de ambientes.

Use com a sintaxe:

```
-v /diretorio/no/hospedeiro:/diretorio/no/container
```

Comment: No caso eu faço um 'link' entre a pasta em que o meu código fonte está armazenado no meu computador com o código que está na imagem certo? 
E então eu não preciso ficar derrubando o container e subindo novamente para testar?

Comment: Exatamente isso. Funciona igual a um diretório compartilhado entre uma máquina virtual e a maquina hospedeira.